# How to create a new object from an API call in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, api, object

I'm trying to create a new object from data retrieved from an API. I modified my code a bit and copied the data from the endpoint but it will be called using fetch. Here's what I have so far:

```js
const urls = [//array of urls]
  
  
const fetchData = async() => {
  try {
    const response = await Promise.all(
      urls.map(url => fetch(url).then(res => res.json()))
    )
    console.log(response)
    if (urls.transfers.status !== 'failed') {
      return {
        originUserName: urls.users.firstName + data.users.lastName,
        targetUserName: urls.targetAccount + urls.users.firstName + urls.users.lastName,
        amount: urls.transfers.amount,
        description: urls.transfers.description,
        likesCount: urls.users.likes
      };
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error", error)
  }
}
```

I keep getting a status is not defined error in my code. I mapped through the array of objects but it looks as though it's not grabbing any of the keys.

Comment: Why should `data.transfers.status` be defined? Your data structure is invalid. The top level is an **array**!! so can't have a property called `transfers`, and none of the properties that are named `transfers` are objects.

Comment: your JS `data` is invalid => `}   [{`

Comment: I was trying to grab the status property and check to see if it was not failed. If so I was going to return a new array of objects

Answer (score 0):

Also you don't have defined user.
You can try this:

```
const users =[{
    "id": 1,
    "user": 2,
    "transfer": 1
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid data. I have amended your data structure and it should look something like this:

```js
const data = [
  [{
      id: 1,
      status: "complete",
      originAccount: 1,
      targetAccount: 4,
      amount: 10000,
      description: "Consider us even >:|",
      initiatedAt: "2019-05-20T12:53:38-04:00",
      completedAt: "2019-05-22T12:00:00-04:00",
      failedAt: null,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      status: "initiated",
      originAccount: 1,
      targetAccount: 7,
      amount: 5500,
      description: "Winner, winner...",
      initiatedAt: "2019-05-23T12:53:38-04:00",
      completedAt: null,
      failedAt: null,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      status: "complete",
      originAccount: 2,
      targetAccount: 5,
      amount: 2500,
      description: "Thanks for the cut!!",
      initiatedAt: "2019-05-04T12:53:38-04:00",
      completedAt: "2019-05-06T12:00:00-04:00",
      failedAt: null,
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      status: "complete",
      originAccount: 7,
      targetAccount: 5,
      amount: 1000,
      description: "Splitting the cab",
      initiatedAt: "2019-05-10T12:53:38-04:00",
      completedAt: "2019-05-12T12:00:00-04:00",
      failedAt: null,
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      status: "failed",
      originAccount: 4,
      targetAccount: 3,
      amount: 1257,
      description: "Drinks :cocktail:",
      initiatedAt: "2019-02-10T12:53:38-04:00",
      completedAt: null,
      failedAt: "2019-02-11T12:00:00-04:00",
    },
  ],
  [
    ({
      id: 1,
      user: 2,
      transfer: 1,
    }, {
      id: 2,
      user: 4,
      transfer: 1,
    }, {
      id: 3,
      user: 4,
      transfer: 3,
    }, {
      id: 4,
      user: 1,
      transfer: 4,
    }),
  ],
  [
    ({
      id: 1,
      firstName: "Aaron",
      lastName: "Howard",
      accounts: [1, 2],
      transfers: [1, 2, 3],
      likes: [4],
    }, {
      id: 2,
      firstName: "Cassie",
      lastName: "Perez",
      accounts: [3],
      transfers: [5],
      likes: [1],
    }, {
      id: 3,
      firstName: "Larry",
      lastName: "Smith",
      accounts: [4],
      transfers: [1, 5],
      likes: [],
    }, {
      id: 4,
      firstName: "Jean",
      lastName: "Sawyer",
      accounts: [5, 6],
      transfers: [3, 4],
      likes: [],
    }, {
      id: 5,
      firstName: "Julie",
      lastName: "Nimmo",
      accounts: [7],
      transfers: [2, 4],
      likes: [],
    }),
  ],
];

//Extract transfers only
const transfers = data.map(d => d)[0];
//Now check status of each transfer
transfers.map((transfer) => {
  if (transfer.status !== 'failed') {
    //...your logic
  }
})
```

Comment: transfers.status comes back with a not defined error and users or likes the same. the only way to traverse everything is through object notation like transfers[0]['status'] for example. is there an easier way to grab the data instead of having to specify which array you want?

Comment: it's transfer.status not transfers.status

Comment: transfer.status also comes back with transfer not defined

Answer (score -1):

- First of all, I just want to point out that the array assigned to
  data is not valid.
- Second, if the data you are receiving is indeed that array, then I see that all keys with the name "transfers" are array of numbers. So the error makes sense.
- Instead of adding a console log after Promise.all, I would rather add a console log by adding a second then within Promise.all. If you could do that and paste it here, that would help us in providing a better solution.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: It's supposed to be 3 separate array of objects. Transfers, Likes, Users. I added a then statement inside the Promise.all and got a reference error `Error ReferenceError: Cannot access 'response' before initialization`